# Leer un .txt con Genexus y obtener datos

Tags: c#, genexus

Tengo la siguiente linea de texto en un .txt :

```
BF2D@Hj040001127874@rV04-56602@iEST@p@l911@n20@e4,040@d6@g@s24@v@Gl70@w-90@l70@w-90@l350@w-90@l70@w-90@l350@w-90@l70@w0@Pw1@C70@
```

Quisiera que al ingresar 127874 me muestre todos los numeros despues de @l como 35 70 70.
Tengo un código de aplicación de consola en c# pero solo obtengo toda la linea donde se encuentra ese numero, y no se a ciencia cierta si genexus entendera mi codigo.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class ReadFriendRecords
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //the path of the file
            FileStream inFile = new FileStream(@"C:\Ruta\prueba.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
            string record;
            string input;
            Console.Write("Ingrese un numero >> ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {

                // el programa lee el registro y lo muestra en la pantalla
                record = reader.ReadLine();
                while (record != null)
                {
                    if (record.Contains(input))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(record);
                    }
                    record = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            finally
            {

                // después de que se haya leído el registro, el programa se cierra
                reader.Close();
                inFile.Close();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Federico, no me queda claro si lo quieres hacer en C# o en GeneXus. Si vas a usar GeneXus tienes que utilizar el tipo de datos File para la lectura del archivo.
De todos modos, en ambos casos yo te recomiendo leer y procesar todo el archivo primero. Leer linea a linea y parsear lo que para ti es clave, que parece ser lo que está entre los 2 primero @s y cargar eso en una estructura que después sea más fáil de buscar. (sobre todo si quieres buscar varias veces y si el archivo no contiene millones de lineas). https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?24070

Comment: La forma mas facil de buscar, es usar Regex, en  lugar de hacer logica para procesar todo el archivo.

Comment: Lo quiero hacer en genexus pero hice una demo en c# para imitar la logica. Aun asi no puedo lograr en Genexus crear un evento boton que al presionarlo me autocomplete los datos en el WP